# subprocess.Popen: can't flush stdin process on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, flush

I wrote a GUI in order to start an external application. This application requires that user press "...any key..." at startup.

I would like to use **subprocess** for portability purpose (no pexpect/wexpect). On Unix OS (Ubuntu, OSX El Capitan) I use this piece of code:

```
...
external_process = subprocess.Popen("./app.exe",
                                    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

external_process.stdin.write("\r\n".encode())
external_process.stdin.flush()
...
```

and it works right. On *Windows* the same code doesn't work.

It seems that flush() doesn't work and "\r\n" never reaches the process

Comment: Are you sure the external application is reading `stdin`? There are other ways of detecting keypresses on Windows.

Comment: As far as I know on Windows it uses _kbhit(), any idea? On Unix version I simulated that piece of code that uses _kbhit() with getchar() disabling buffering

Comment: `kbhit()` is a hardware (BIOS) level function on Windows, so you would need something that operated at that level. You might be able to use [`msvcrt.ungetch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o), but I am not sure it would work between processes.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Using wexpect (pseudo terminal) it works, do you know a way to create a pseudo terminal in order to run the application from it without using external library (pure Python)? Many thanks

Comment: No sorry. I don't even know what a "pseudo terminal" is.

Comment: If you look at the library used by pexpect for its TTY handling, you'll have more to go on re: creating a pty in pure Python and launching subprocesses attached to it.

Comment: From docs: "The main features of Pexpect require the pty module in the Python standard library, which is only available on Unix-like systems". Maybe the only simple approach is to use wexpect